# Compared to APK file, are apps installed from AAB (Android App Bundle) impacting their performance?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, installation

I'm just a normal Android user. My phone is Samsung Galaxy S10 (Qualcomm S855 variant). I'm satisfied with this phone, but I always felt that the Android version of some Apps are laggy when using, like: **Twitter**, **YouTube**, **Google Maps**, and even the **Google Play Store**. You will feel the **scrolling stutter and lag in many scene**. Although it's three years old phone, I don't think it doesn't have enough performance to running these apps. I've tested on another phones (Galaxy Note10) and the situation is same.  So I think the application itself has optimization problems, or the latest version has bug.

I have tried **Clear App Cache** and **Re-install again from Play Store**. The problem is remains, so I turn off autoupdate in Play Store and install **previous** version through **APK** (Download from APK Mirror), all the problems are solved, it's working well and feel smooth when you scrolling or do any operation, and then I tried install the **latest** version of **APK**, it's still not have any problem, working perfectly too.

I know that the apps installed from Google Play Store are distributed in the **Android App Bundle (AAB)** format. *So here is the question: will the **AAB** make Android apps laggy?*

Comment: Android apps are uploaded to PlayStore using AAB but the AAB is never distributed to the device. Instead for each app a a set of APK files (sometimes called split APK) is downloaded by the device and installed together as one app. Was the version you installed a one-APK file or a set of APK files (e.g. in APKS or XAPK format)?

Comment: Thank your reply, i only installed one APK file (Variant:APK Arch:universal dpi:nodpi)both of them

Comment: Then you can test your hypothesis yourself. Instead of using an universal APK install the APKS variant of the same version and check if it behaves differently.

Comment: The version from the Play Store may have been corrupted after multiple updates, which can happen to any app. Android can (depending on Android version, device manufacturer) keep install data after uninstalling an app, and if you reinstall soon enough it just uses that existing data. Restarting the device cleans out uninstalled apps.

Comment: @Robert  i tried, doesn't feel any different but can be clearly felt is that App installed form Play Store is unsmooth than i manuel install